# How to create reusable controls using knockout, jquery, and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm wanting to create reusable controls which get used on a knockout / jquery / asp.net mvc page

For instance, various items can have a discussion  ( a list of comments).   I want a discussion control which handles showing and adding comments, etc.

initial thoughts are to use a partial view to inject the html, and then have .js file with some javascript that sets up the knockout viewmodel.   It seems a bit clunky though.  I'm just wondering if someone has a really nice way of doing all this and packaging it up as a nice control?

Comment: vote to close as not constructive?  I'm specifically asking for someones expertise on how to create reususable controls using asp.net mvc/knocout and jquery.  That fits the format of stackoverflow :-)

Comment: This question has too much depth and there are dozens of ways to accomplish it.  Once customization and options start getting adding in the complexity skyrockets and you start having to discuss API usability and things like composition vs inheritance.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I need to do something similar - I use an Editor Template to render a collection of child objects. This works fine and names each object correctly for MVC binding e.g. Category.Products[0].ProductName, etc. Now I need to figure out how to bind the properties of each child object to my knockout view model.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is one approach.**

---

You have a separate WebAPI controller for handling the data access from the clientside.

```
//Inside your CommentsApiController, for example
public IEnumerable<Comment> Get(int id)
{
    var comments = _commentsService.Get(int id);    //Call lower layers to get the data you need
    return comments;
}
```

---

Your MVC controllers have actions which return `PartialViewResults`. It is a simple action which returns a partial view.

```
//Inside your MVC CommentsController, for example
public PartialViewResult CommentsList(int id)
{
    return PartialView(id);
}
```

---

Your partial view renders out your markup, with knockout bindings. We make a unique ID for our HTML so we can bind our knockout viewmodel to this specific section of the page (avoid conflicting with other knockout components on the page).
The JavaScript we require (knockout viewmodels etc) gets included, a new ViewModel created and knockout bindings applied.

```
@{
    var commentsId = Model;    //passed from our MVC action
    var uniqueIid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
<section class="comments" id="@uniqueIid ">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: Comments, as: 'comment' }">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: comment.Author"></span>
            <p data-bind="text: comment.Message"></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>


@Scripts.Render("~/js/comments")    //using MVC Bundles to include the required JS
@{
    //generate the URL to our WebAPI endpoint.
    var url = Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { httproute = "", controller = "Comments", id = commentsId });
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var commentsRepository = new CommentsRepository('@url');
        var commentsViewModel = new CommentsViewModel(commentsRepository);

        var commentsElement = $('#@uniqueIid')[0];
        ko.applyBindings(commentsViewModel, commentsElement);
    });
</script>
```

---

Inside our JavaScript, we define our knockout viewmodels etc.

```
var CommentsRepository = function(url) {
    var self = this;
    self.url = url;

    self.Get = function(callback) {
        $.get(url).done(function(comments) {
            callback(comments);
        });
    };
};

var CommentsViewModel = function (commentsRepository) {
    var self = this;
    self.CommentsRepository = commentsRepository;
    self.Comments = ko.observableArray([]);

    //self executing function to Get things started
    self.init = (function() {
        self.CommentsRepository.Get(function(comments) {
            self.Comments(comments);
        });
    })();
};
```

---

And we're done! To use this new component, we can use `RenderAction`

```
@* inside our Layout or another View *@
<article>
    <h1>@article.Name</h1>
    <p>main page content here blah blah blah</p>
    <p>this content is so interesting I bet people are gonna wanna comment about it</p>
</article>
@Html.RenderAction("Comments", "CommentsList", new { id = article.id })
```

Answer (score 0):

If, with "control", you mean the type of control we're used to from ASP.NET WebForms, the closest thing you have in ASP.NET MVC, is [HTML Helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs). Since they are basically just regular .NET methods returning [`HtmlString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx), you can easily package anything you want inside an assembly containing these methods along with [embedded resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2c9s1d7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (for JavaScript, CSS and image files).

Comment: no, not so much like webforms, though the goal is similar...  its just making a reusable component that hooks in with knockout.   HTML Helpers are cool, and that might be part of the solution, but knockout means you have to inject into the client side creation process at the right times to inject your 'control'

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to automatically hookup your html to knockout, take a look at my plug-in at https://github.com/phototom/ko-autobind.

This is still a work-in progress.  To use it, take a look a demo fiddle a http://jsfiddle.net/rxXyC/11/.

You can also see list of some available plug-in's at https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Plugins

Comment: I can't seem to make your demo fiddle work. Also, given that it's been a while since the autobind repository was updated, could you perhaps update the readme with known issues etc? :)

Comment: You're right. Ill wget it fixed in a couple of days when I get back home.